# I got an error at da.Fill(ds) command for my shopping cart project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is my final-year mini-project. I tried to implement a shopping cart project.
But I get an error in filling details on gridview. I tried the below coding:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim dr As DataRow
    dt.Columns.Add("sno")
    dt.Columns.Add("productid")
    dt.Columns.Add("productname")
    dt.Columns.Add("price")
    dt.Columns.Add("productimage")
    dt.Columns.Add("cost")
    dt.Columns.Add("totalcost")
    If Request.QueryString("id") IsNot Nothing Then
        If Session("Buyitems") Is Nothing Then
            dr = dt.NewRow()
            Dim mycon As String = "Data Source=Sandy-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"
            Dim scon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(mycon)
            Dim myquery As String = "select * from decorativestands where Id=" & Request.QueryString("id")
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = myquery
            cmd.Connection = scon
            Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds)
            dr("sno") = 1
            dr("productid") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("productid").ToString()
            dr("productname") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("productname").ToString()
            dr("productimage") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("productimage").ToString()
            dr("price") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("price").ToString()
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
            Session("buyitems") = dt
        Else
            dt = CType(Session("buyitems"), DataTable)
            Dim sr As Integer
            sr = dt.Rows.Count
            dr = dt.NewRow()
```

I got "sqlexception was unhandled by user code" error.

Comment: Is there anything more to the error message to say what the SqlException was?

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Always post the entire exception message, and include the line that is throwing the exception.  Dispose your data objects.

Comment: according yo my vb coding...Request.QueryString("id")  that get the value from the database but da.Fill(ds) command did not fill the details of that id to the respective gridview....                                                                                                                                                           I did not get any official error but it shows "invlaid column name'id' " as sqlexception was unhandled by user code. @AndrewMorton

Comment: I copied the exception detail it shows                                                                                                             .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  Class=16     ErrorCode=-2146232060            
  Message=Invalid column name 'ST01'.       
 @LarsTech

Comment: Which line is failing ? I don't see ST01 in your code so I don't think you posted all of it. Anyway, the message is rather obvious: either the column name doesn't exist or it's not included in your SQL query.

Comment: @EmeraldCaroDythosh You will have to use an SQL parameter for the value of `Id` otherwise it is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and typos. So, `Dim myquery = "select * from decorativestands where Id = @Id"`, and `cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "Id", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.putTheCorrectTypeHere, .Value = Request.QueryString("id")})`. Add the conversion of the QueryString value to the correct type, such as `CInt`, and if it is a string type then also put `.Size = ` and the size as declared in the database.

Comment: @EmeraldCaroDythosh If that is the actual code, then perhaps the value of `Request.QueryString("id")` is not what you intended; it looks like there is an `&` missing before `ST01`.

Comment: I always find it incredible when people ask for help with SQL code and yet don't bother to post the SQL code. The VB code that constructs the SQL is not the SQL code. We can probably guess what the issue is but we shouldn't have to. I bet you haven't even looked at the SQL code yourself which is even worse. Look at the actual SQL code to see if you can see the issue. If you can't, show us that SQL code. Don't hide the code from those you want to fix it.

Comment: I see a problem with your connection string. `Initial Catalog=master;` is probably not the database you want to connect to. What is the name of your database? Initial Catalog should be the name of your database.

Comment: What is the primary key field in this table? Is it an identity field?